# Failed to start Elasticsearch. Error opening log file '/gc.log': Permission denied

Tags: elasticsearch

Dear StackOverflow community,

I was running Kibana/Elasticsearch without a problem until installing a Kibana plugin. Then the service failed and I noticed that the problem is that Elasticsearch stopped. I tried several ways to fix it, and then even reinstalled all. But the problem still avoiding to launch Elasticsearch, even with a fresh installation.

Installation on Debian 9 using apt install.

`systemctl start elasticsearch.service`

results on:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]`

`[0.000s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/gc.log': Permission denied`

Full log with `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Unit elasticsearch.service has begun starting up.
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal kibana[576]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-02-07T13:09:06Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":576,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal kibana[576]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-02-07T13:09:06Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":576,"message":"No living connections"}
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal kibana[576]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-02-07T13:09:06Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":576,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal kibana[576]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-02-07T13:09:06Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":576,"message":"No living connections"}
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: output:
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: [0.000s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/gc.log': Permission denied
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: [0.000s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log' using options 'filecount=32,filesize=64m' failed.
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: error:
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:118)
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:86)
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:59)
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal elasticsearch[2312]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:92)
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 07 14:09:06 Debian-911-stretch-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
-- Subject: Unit elasticsearch.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit elasticsearch.service has failed.
```

The mentioned gc.log file was not in that folder. And the permissions were:

`drwxr-s---  2 elasticsearch elasticsearch       4096 Jan 15 13:20 elasticsearch`

I created the file and also played with permissions until having these:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root elasticsearch 0 Feb  7 15:19 gc.log`

...and even changed the ownership:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 15:19 gc.log`

But no success, I still having the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: did you try to set permission to elasticsearch log and data folder? or just gc.log?

Comment: I changed permissions for both the gc.log file and the /var/log/elasticsearch folder. Even with 777 still happening the same problem...

Comment: can you post  elasticsearch.log?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are running [CMD as Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkQEY.png).

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: I'm going to respectfully disagree here @Tyler2P. This is a complete answer in my case and probably for many others.

Answer (score 3):

This error also happens if you are using docker & running the container as a different user. You have to add `--group_add` flag to docker command or set `TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP` environment variable as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_configuration_files_must_be_readable_by_the_elasticsearch_user)

Using docker-compose:

```yaml
    user: 1007:1007
    group_add: 
        - 0
```

Using docker:
`--group-add 0`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I didn't know why gc.log file was not present. Have you changed the logs folder path or something? The gc.log path can be set in `jvm.options` file. By default ES logs and java garbage collection logs are fed into the logs folder inside $ES_HOME directory.

About `user` perspective, elastic search **can't be run as root user.** So from the ES directory details its showing you have an `elasticsearch` user created, and trying to run the cluster by that user.

The problem here can be solved by changing the permissions of files insdie the ES directory where all it belongs. Now the gc.log file is owned by root user and it cannot be accessed by the elasticsearch user.

Try this: `sudo chown <user> <path/to/es/directory> -R`

Here it becomes : `sudo chown elasticsearch elasticsearch/ -R`

If the issue still persists, check the **jvm.options** file whether its all configured correctly. Unless you change the `-Xloggc:logs/gc.log` option, the gc.log won't be pushing to `/var/log`.

```
Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]: Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
```

Your log says, the option is given as *file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log*. Correct any wrong configurations as per documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/jvm-options.html

Comment: I did a fresh install, but thanks a lot because your reply gave us more light about the permission issues with Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo systemctl -l status elasticsearch.service`

Returns this log:

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-02-09 17:09:02 CET; 2min 48s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 2199 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2199 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]: Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:118)
Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:86)
Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:59)
Feb 09 17:09:02 server elasticsearch[2199]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:92)
Feb 09 17:09:02 server systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 09 17:09:02 server systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 09 17:09:02 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

At this point I'm doing a fresh install. Not able to find the solution I need to continue working...